# Nautilus Actions embedded not working right

Tags: arch-linux, nautilus

I installed Nautilus Actions from Community (nautilus-actions) and the Nautilus Terminal from Community (nautilus-terminal). I can see the terminal (screenshot http://screencloud.net/v/EknY) and I made a simple Nautilus Action to use Filebot (another screenshot http://screencloud.net/v/ohJf) so as you can see from the second screenshot I chose Embedded which should run the command inside the nautilus-terminal but it doesn't. It always launches a new gnome-terminal.

Versions 
Nautilus: GNOME nautilus 3.12.2 
Nautilus Actions: nautilus-actions-config-tool (Nautilus-Actions) v 3.2.3

Answer (score -2):

After successful installation of Nautilus Terminal, we are ready to test it but before that it is necessary to restart nautilus as.

```
$ nautilus -q
```

Next, start the nautilus terminal using the following command.

```
$ nautilus
```

Comment: The question does not appear to be asking how to run `nautilus`, but rather why embedding `nautilus-actions` is not functioning properly.